# LSTM Forecasting

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

If anyone is there to answer these, that'll be great. I'm in the midst of a Final Year Project on LSTM.

Currently, I’m stuck and confused over LSTM codes. There are 4 hyperparameters that I can play around.
- Look back
- Batch size
- LSTM units
- No. of Epochs
Can you explain what will happen to my results if I tune each of these hyperparameters? 
And also is it common if we get different results each time we run the codes?

Comment: The reason why I ask was that whenever I tune the results, there is not much of a difference. Usually, I will compare it with Mean Square Error to check its accuracy.

Comment: This is not a good match for StackOverflow, try https://datascience.stackexchange.com. Apart from that, Batch size and number of epochs are orthogonal to LSTM. "Look back" -- assuming it's for how many steps you unroll -- will be heavily problem-dependent.

Comment: haha @dedObed wait why is it not a good match for stackoverflow?

Comment: Because SO is for specific programming questions. What you ask is neither specific, nor programming: a language agnostic, toolkit agnostic question about a machine learning model and its (unspecified) training procedure hyperparameters. See e.g. [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).